# Robotframework : How to chunk a binary file or read the file chunk by chunk

Tags: robotframework, binaryfiles

I have a variable with the binary file read it from a file in Robotframework:

${fileData}=    Get Binary File    ${CHUNK_GEOJSON_FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}

This keyword read the entire file, no arguments to determine the among of bytes to be read. So what I actually need is to save in ${fileData} only 1MB, or I need to separate the entire file into differents chunks(1Mb) because I will use those chunks to upload the file by chunks using the PATCH from the tus protocol.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are using can get all file details at one go. Can't separate with size that you are intended to do.
I suggest you writing python function and call that as keyword to do this activity.